# How to add strings while naming a sheet in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I was able to do it in a macro with the below line,

```
Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(current)).Name = Format(Date, "ddmmyy") + " deciles"
```

But a similar line is not working in a different macro

```
Worksheets.Add.Name = "Performance classification" + Format(Date, "ddmmyy")
```

I am getting the runtime error 1004 - application-defined or object defined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Worksheets.Add.Name = "Perform class " & Format(Date, "ddmmyy")
```

If you use "Performance classification" the name will be too long, > 31 characters.

The expression works with and without the parenthses too.

Answer (score 2):

Try: `Worksheets.Add().Name = "Performance classification" + Format(Date, "ddmmyy")`

In the line of code that works, `Worksheets.Add` is a method that you're calling to create *and return* a new worksheet. Then you're invoking the `Name` property and setting it to a new value. VBA needs you to use parentheses on the `Add` method to denote that you care about the return value (the new worksheet object)

Comment: It is not working. It works if I comment out "+ Format(Date, "ddmmyy")", but that part is what is important for me.